# SSRS 2008 won't let me override User!UserID with a data driven subscription

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, data-driven

I have one SSRS report with two linked reports pointing at it.

One is for users to click and view their data. Behind the scenes, I need it to pass `User!UserID` as a parameter and hide it.

On the other report, I need to set up a data driven subscription that passes the `UserID` as a value from the database.

If I publish the report with the parameter defaulted to a value of `User!UserID`, it will not let me save the subscription and gives an error of

> "The '/Admin/Subscriptions/Recruiting Sign Ups' report or shared dataset has user profile dependencies and cannot be run unattended. (rsHasUserProfileDependencies) Get Online Help"

If I remove the default value from the report definition, the subscription works but I cannot get the other linked report to pass `UserID` as a hidden parameter using the Parameters tab on the SSRS interface (rather than in the RDL definition).

Is there a workaround to this that does not involve VB?

Answer (score 1):

So to rephrase you have report A which you use as a subreport in reports B and C. to be able to make a subsciption to report A you need to remove the default value for the user parameter. the user parameter in report A is hidden and with a default value because you don't want users to be able to set it to someone else.

so there are two ways to solve the issue: get data driven subscriptions accept a default value, or find a way to pass parameters from reports B and C

pass parameters from report B and C: 
the interface won't allow you to set hidden parameters, but it works. just open report A, change the parameter to visible, open report B and C, map the parameter, go back to A, set the parameter to hidden again.

get data driven subscriptions to accept a default value:
SSRS tries to be smart by finding out that the parameter has a default value set, but it shouldn't be too hard to fool. try getting the default value from a dataset which uses a sql username function, or something in this direction..